Solana Validator Not Opening RPC Port 8899
I’m running a Solana validator on my server and trying to open RPC port 8899 using the following configuration in my systemd service:
--rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \--rpc-port 8899 \--private-rpc \--full-rpc-apiThe issue is that port 8899 is not opening and is inaccessible (both externally and locally). Here are the details:    •    Firewall is not active (ufw status confirms it’s disabled).    •    Port 8899 is not used by any other application (netstat and lsof confirm this).    •    Validator runs without errors according to the logs.    •    I’ve tried different RPC ports and --rpc-bind-address parameters without success.    •    The server has sufficient resources, and RPC options are configured as per the Solana documentation.Server Details:    •    Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)    •    Kernel Version: 5.15.0-130-generic    •    Motherboard: ASRockRack B650D4U, UEFI version 20.01 (dated 06/20/2024)    •    CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 9950X, 16 cores, 32 threads, base clock 3.0 GHz, max boost 4.3 GHz, L3 cache 64 MB    •    RAM: 92 GiB total, ~2% used    •    Storage:    •    1 x NVMe SSD Crucial CT4000P3PSSD8 (3.64 TiB, temp: 27.9 °C)    •    1 x USB drive PNY USB 2.0 FD (28.85 GiB)    •    Network Interfaces:    •    Intel I210 Gigabit Network (up, 1000 Mbps, full duplex)    •    2 additional interfaces (down)    •    Graphics: ASPEED Graphics Family (server is headless, no display server)    •    Audio Devices: Integrated AMD audio, ALSA active    •    Swap: 3.73 GiB (0.5% used)Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this issue or what else I can check?here is log files: inner: [            "/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/agave-validator",            "--no-voting",            "--ledger",            "/root/solana/ledger",            "--accounts",            "/root/solana/accounts",            "--rpc-bind-address",            "0.0.0.0",            "--rpc-port",            "8899",            "--public-rpc-address",            "199.231.186.90:8899",            "--full-rpc-api",            "--log",            "/root/RPC/agave/agave-validator.log",            "--limit-ledger-size",            "50000000",            "--snapshot-interval-slots",            "100",            "--identity",            "/root/config/validator-wallet.json",            "--entrypoint",            "entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001",            "--entrypoint",            "entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001",            "--entrypoint",            "entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001",            "--known-validator",            "7XSy3MrYnK8vq693Rju17bbPkCN3Z7KvvfvJx4kdrsSY",            "--known-validator",            "GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ",            "--known-validator",            "DE1Bx4J8Uug4zGwJrHiddAYdV9EUNWxTPzSES5ySXUJ4",            "--dynamic-port-range",            "8002-8020",        ],    }[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.628276874Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m CUDA is disabled[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.628280842Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m AVX detected[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.628282315Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m AVX2 detected[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757262592Z [0m[32mINFO [0m agave_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m obtained shred-version 50093 from 147.28.180.247:8001[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757447056Z [0m[32mINFO [0m agave_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m Snapshot configuration: full snapshot interval: 25000 slots, incremental snapshot interval: 100 slots[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757481060Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m metrics disabled: environment variable not found[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757644425Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   net.core.rmem_max: recommended=134217728 current=134217728[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757648763Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   net.core.rmem_default: recommended=134217728 current=134217728[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757650657Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   net.core.wmem_max: recommended=134217728 current=134217728[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757652140Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   net.core.wmem_default: recommended=134217728 current=134217728[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757653983Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   vm.max_map_count: recommended=1000000 current=1000000[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757655376Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   net.core.optmem_max: report-only --  current=134217728[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757657179Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_core::system_monitor_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m   net.core.netdev_max_backlog: report-only --  current=65536[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757658532Z [0m[32mINFO [0m agave_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m OS network limits test passed.[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757691223Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config platform="unix/linux/x86_64"[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757735646Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config net.core.rmem_max=134217728i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757739793Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config net.core.rmem_default=134217728i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757742899Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config net.core.wmem_max=134217728i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757745394Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config net.core.wmem_default=134217728i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757749582Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config vm.max_map_count=1000000i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757752678Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config net.core.optmem_max=134217728i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757754691Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: os-config net.core.netdev_max_backlog=65536i[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.757838798Z [0m[32mINFO [0m agave_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m Contacting 147.28.180.247:8001 to determine the validator's public IP address[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.758142827Z [0m[32mINFO [0m agave_validator::admin_rpc_service[0m[38;5;8m][0m started admin rpc service![0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.885583988Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m host id: 9SmfhoiWrkjMtSaSfYg5zugUDxaELogHXeeqhBwBxhR8[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.885642487Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_entry::entry[0m[38;5;8m][0m Loading "libpoh-simd.so"[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.885685818Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_perf::perf_libs[0m[38;5;8m][0m perf-libs found at "/root/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-99ac010533749c74b308bfd932cbf92f9f81dffa/solana-release/bin/perf-libs"[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.885690567Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_perf::perf_libs[0m[38;5;8m][0m setting ld_library_path to: "/root/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-99ac010533749c74b308bfd932cbf92f9f81dffa/solana-release/bin/perf-libs"[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.885843313Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m Checking that tcp ports [(8899, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8899, fd: 83 }), (8900, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8900, fd: 84 }), (8002, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8002, fd: 85 })] are reachable from 145.40.64.255:8001[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.893302861Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m tcp/8899 is reachable[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.893432944Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m tcp/8900 is reachable[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.893501191Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m tcp/8002 is reachable[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:41.893564379Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m Checking that udp ports [8002, 8003, 8005, 8006, 8007, 8008, 8009, 8010, 8011, 8012, 8014] are reachable from 145.40.64.255:8001[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:42.157985287Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m checked udp ports: [8002, 8003, 8005, 8006], reachable udp ports: {8002, 8006, 8005, 8003}[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:42.413417482Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m checked udp ports: [8007, 8008, 8009, 8010], reachable udp ports: {8009, 8010, 8008, 8007}[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:42.701380542Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_net_utils[0m[38;5;8m][0m checked udp ports: [8011, 8012, 8014], reachable udp ports: {8012, 8011, 8014}[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:42.707605712Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_gossip::cluster_info[0m[38;5;8m][0m Loaded contact info for 5689 nodes from /root/solana/ledger/contact-info.bin[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-12-21T14:03:43.717359155Z [0m[32mINFO [0m agave_validator::bootstrap[0m[38;5;8m][0m    RPC Address       |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version | RPC  |PubSub|ShredVer    ------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------    18.196.30.68      |    35 | 9rkJMARqK6VBkcxGfKBAwnA44gPAfGxPbPsfsggFNDSQ | 2.0.18  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    72.46.84.195      |    33 | hyp3Eo67t6FgeuWg5Qxbeme8NPXJPXXdKT4iJ4DsLf2  | 2.0.17  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    65.20.105.6       |   111 | BNHc65eh9XMBeDSmLTi5jX8CjtUemMsKFs2zpdqsbnWW | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    162.19.102.192    |    40 | 7mF8NZJdREuM1uwYcvKffuY9QJBEoHhNp4hZ4NS2fuXW | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    91.242.214.51     |   107 | 6ajJvpm8gdqKyVhaYJ44geWi1CR64qKJYdLPwsdCBtBk |  2.1.4  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    176.99.142.188    |    36 | 2VKu11f8zc3huqDQUN6WJTFpX32PgHpXXjf72P6YvYMd | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    84.32.186.145     |    40 | 5WNrMVfywRpYzLqwkkBocsX3W46x36EKoW4FX74FyopC | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    65.20.102.96      |   104 | ByszyWdqC3rVMWy8f6jwK5cmwkpwYdwsr7UL58xS5vnm | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    162.19.222.39     |   110 | EvnRmnMrd69kFdbLMxWkTn1icZ7DCceRhvmb2SJXqDo4 | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    147.75.92.135     |    38 | mds4GEuiSgQRqveGyktWpETBFCb4AS2wDnhqwLHcT6Z  |  2.2.0  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    45.77.136.52      |   168 | FyrwfMaomErzqrFUXMjCJ7mA4u81DsiDdrzC3MJD6d4j | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    217.110.201.118   |    71 | CHaH4FPhSKqH59E77R3GkpUGnHeLfXnT5wFCpLNw6JWH | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    177.54.154.27     |   110 | SANDigkxQHytCJDcoCL2CzxW7eDuVSVNMVaUUvDVPh2  | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    216.238.72.116    |    90 | mastWEbKEMjvBCd1uaUBpNjWcfSPhXMWnH9tTrgzn1g  | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    45.250.254.191    |    35 | 5zuNci3TV79w6zLoJZzbZujMvkVZb2FcSPhgv9aT24AK | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    207.148.65.229    |    38 | CHikKUoYJDqFK5mPPtQ4ip63n4DZbsz9gMEGJ6a3t3o  | 2.0.17  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    66.135.11.69      |   103 | 6Rk694kh1QTyQkirdb1uDZmS5xqG9bNaYtxx8d311Mr7 | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    149.248.62.208    |    40 | 2Rv9npqdWE1mLPsT1r2obn3xtKmA5afkxt8GsWeLnKoc | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    45.135.201.155    |    35 | Ey3DkEVbfBxfWmkTsG7Hqj7jshYf5Zx9H8462Zjjkykf | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    89.44.211.18      |    31 | HSX42dhQPTaVjtwMQXwGTCobrs1HnxZ8G2J6JTnPXpgP | 2.0.16  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    47.76.169.204     |   108 | Fc6NNdS2j3EmrWbU6Uqt6wsKB5ef72NjaWfNxKYbULGD | 2.0.18  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    185.26.11.107     |    37 | FBKFWadXZJahGtFitAsBvbqh5968gLY7dMBBJUoUjeNi | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093    37.61.218.226     |    37 | Ed9WjPnZfAXsPttcqxMwj94qsuXVRyBsyXnDkxFva2Zv | 2.0.19  | 8899 | 8900 | 50093Thanks in advance!

There seems to be a contradiction, since you say you're providing --private-rpc but then the logs show that you're also setting --public-rpc-address. Maybe there's something else we're missing?
